# React js css transitions on class removal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, css-transitions

I have column that should have different width depending on some flag. I use Bootstrap, so I assign `col-xs-12` and `col-xs-2` depending on the flag.

Now I want it to change width slowly with css transition. I've read [official React.js doc about transitions](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html), but it doesn't apply to my case: I need transition already mounted element from one state to another. TransitionGroup is convenient for adding and removal transitions, but not changing shape of existing elements.

I've made an example to demonstrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/5pvkjwth/

It does collapses slowly but expanding does not work as expected.

Is it something related to how React works? Or I just use `min-width` property wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a `width` transition, since the `width` CSS property is defined on both the `col-xs-2` and `col-xs-12` classes.

http://jsfiddle.net/5pvkjwth/2/

Comment: Whoa, that's awesome!